# Problem with News URL of Category and tags

Tags: typo3, seo, tx-news, typo3-10.x

Following is my code for making the news page URL user-friendly. The detail page URL is working well with this but it's not working for Category and tags.

```
News:
type: Extbase
limitToPages:
  - 16
extension: News
plugin: Pi1
routes:
  -
    routePath: '/page/{page}'
    _controller: 'News::list'
    _arguments:
      page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
  -
    routePath: '/{news_title}'
    _controller: 'News::detail'
    _arguments:
      news_title: news
  -
    routePath: '/topic/{category_name}'
    _controller: 'News::list'
    _arguments:
      category_name: overwriteDemand/categories
  - 
    routePath: '/tag/{tag_name}'
      _controller: 'News::list'
      _arguments:
        tag_name: 'overwriteDemand/tags'
defaultController: 'News::list'
defaults:
  page: '0'
requirements:
  news_title: '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
aspects:
  news_title:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
    routeFieldName: path_segment
  page:
    type: StaticRangeMapper
    start: '1'
    end: '100'
  category_name:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: sys_category
    routeFieldName: path_segment
  tag_name:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_news_domain_model_tag
    routeFieldName: slug
```

Anyone, please help me to find out what's wrong with this?
I have already commented the `skipControllerAndAction = 1`

*Typo3 version - 10.4.16,
news - 8.5.2*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your routePath for categories does not meet your defined requirements (There is no `news_title`).

[Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#plugin-enhancer) says:

> If the input given to generate the URL does not meet the requirements, the route enhancer does not offer the variant and the parameters are added to the URL as regular query parameters.

Just move the requirement in the routePath they belong to (The one for the detail view).

*Update: corrected YAML to clarify the needed change*

```
News:
    ...
    routes:
      -
        ...
      -
        routePath: '/{news_title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news_title: news
        requirements:
          news_title: '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '1'        
    aspects:
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
      ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thx for the reply.

news_title is for detail page. i have given /topic/{category_name} for the category

Comment: Your requirements for `news_title` are defined globally, so it is a requirement for *all* of your news routes. So your `routePath: '/topic/{category_name}'`must have a `news_title`, too - which is not the case. Your requirement should be moved in the block of your `routePath: '/{news_title}'`, so it gets required only for these routes.

Comment: Thx. 

I just need to list out news accordingly tags and categories. so I don't need a news title there. 
Thank you for your explanations I will check it.